# How to make mobile menu full-width

Tags: css, mobile, hamburger-menu, divi

I cannot figure out, **how to make mobile menu full-width**. When I click on hamburger menu, it opens up, but it's only like regular dropdown.I tried many ways to change it, but can't figure it out.

Here is the link: https://dev.povoden.cz/

Comment: Please put just enough code direct into your question to show the problem, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Add style **position: static** to class "et_pb_menu_inner_container" and "et_pb_column--with-menu"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following way.

```css
.et_mobile_menu {
  position: fixed; /* Instead of absolute */
  top: 90px !important; /* Adjust it to set the top value */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I am not sure which version and such you are using. Whilst divi does some great things in terms of making building easier. It means they often make it very difficult to find out why normal CSS doesn't seem to work.

I have a similar issue and I was using the theme builder to build a global header. None of the CSS I tried seemed to work.

I was unable to find where the width was being set and how to overwrite it.

The solution in the end was simple.

When in the theme builder.
New Section (fullwidth)
New Row (full width) - THIS is what actually fixes the problem

Please checkout the attached screen shot
[how to adjust the menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAXbu.png)